# How can I add a batch of data to a batch of data in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I insert data from a file into my database:

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO people (id,name,item1) values(?,?,?) ";
   $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);

   foreach($data as $row) {
       $q->execute(array($id, $row['name'], $row['item']);  
   }
```

The result looks like this:

```
╔═════╦═══════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ id  ║ name  ║  item1  ║  item2  ║
╠═════╬═══════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ 12  ║ fred  ║ 24C8EI  ║         ║
║ 12  ║ alan  ║ 767CG5  ║         ║
║ 12  ║ tom   ║ 382F74  ║         ║
╚═════╩═══════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

Until this step everything works fine.

Now I want to update my database with the data of a copy of the file (to check if the copy has the same content. I want to compare later item1 and item2 if it is the same). My try is not working:

```
$sql = "UPDATE people SET item2 = ? WHERE id = 12";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach($data as $row) {
   $q->execute(array($row['item'], $id));
}
```

I think I have some logical problem. I hope I explained enough to understand what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `id = 12;` from your query.Because you pass two parameter in your execute statement

It would be

```
$id=12;// initlize you id
$sql = "UPDATE people SET item2 = ? WHERE id = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach($data as $row) {
   $q->execute(array($row['item'], $id));
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, I tried as you said, but it is still not working

Comment: Hello, my result is a white empty page.

Comment: use this `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);` to check error in page

Comment: Hi, I wrote it on the top of my page, but still I do not get any error messages, just a white page

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible, it is too long